# Python, argparse command line argument Assertion Error

Tags: python, argparse

My command line arguments that use argparse returns AssertionError. I have two scripts and a directory that stores three data files.

Script:

- main.py which does a job of loading data
- data.py which does pre-processing for language data

Data:

- three tokens are stored in C:\Users\archive path

**data.py script**

```
**#data.py**
import os
from io import open
import torch

class Dictionary(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.word2idx = {}
        self.idx2word = []

    def add_word(self, word):
        if word not in self.word2idx:
            self.idx2word.append(word)
            self.word2idx[word] = len(self.idx2word) - 1
        return self.word2idx[word]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.idx2word)

class Corpus(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.dictionary = Dictionary()
        self.train = self.tokenize(os.path.join(path, 'train.txt'))
        self.valid = self.tokenize(os.path.join(path, 'valid.txt'))
        self.test = self.tokenize(os.path.join(path, 'test.txt'))

    def tokenize(self, path):
        """Tokenizes a text file."""
        assert os.path.exists(path)
        # Add words to the dictionary
        with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            for line in f:
                words = line.split() + ['<eos>']
                for word in words:
                    self.dictionary.add_word(word)

        # Tokenize file content
        with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            idss = []
            for line in f:
                words = line.split() + ['<eos>']
                ids = []
                for word in words:
                    ids.append(self.dictionary.word2idx[word])
                idss.append(torch.tensor(ids).type(torch.int64))
            ids = torch.cat(idss)

        return ids
```

**main.py script**

```
**#main.py**
import argparse
import time
import math
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.onnx

import data

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch Wikitext-2 RNN/LSTM/GRU/Transformer Language Model')
parser.add_argument('--data', type=str, default='./data/wikitext-2',
                    help='location of the data corpus')
parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, default='LSTM',
                    help='type of recurrent net (RNN_TANH, RNN_RELU, LSTM, GRU, Transformer)')
parser.add_argument('--emsize', type=int, default=200,
                    help='size of word embeddings')
parser.add_argument('--nhid', type=int, default=200,
                    help='number of hidden units per layer')
parser.add_argument('--nlayers', type=int, default=2,
                    help='number of layers')
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=20,
                    help='initial learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--clip', type=float, default=0.25,
                    help='gradient clipping')
parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=40,
                    help='upper epoch limit')
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=20, metavar='N',
                    help='batch size')
parser.add_argument('--bptt', type=int, default=35,
                    help='sequence length')
parser.add_argument('--dropout', type=float, default=0.2,
                    help='dropout applied to layers (0 = no dropout)')
parser.add_argument('--tied', action='store_true',
                    help='tie the word embedding and softmax weights')
parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=1111,
                    help='random seed')
parser.add_argument('--cuda', action='store_true',
                    help='use CUDA')
parser.add_argument('--log-interval', type=int, default=200, metavar='N',
                    help='report interval')
parser.add_argument('--save', type=str, default='model.pt',
                    help='path to save the final model')
parser.add_argument('--onnx-export', type=str, default='',
                    help='path to export the final model in onnx format')
parser.add_argument('--nhead', type=int, default=2,
                    help='the number of heads in the encoder/decoder of the transformer model')
parser.add_argument('--dry-run', action='store_true',
                    help='verify the code and the model')

args = parser.parse_args()

# Set the random seed manually for reproducibility.
torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    if not args.cuda:
        print("WARNING: You have a CUDA device, so you should probably run with --cuda")

device = torch.device("cuda" if args.cuda else "cpu")

###############################################################################
# Load data
###############################################################################

corpus = data.Corpus(args.data)
```

**When I run main.py in terminal:**

```
$ python main.py
```

**The assertionError appears as below:**

```
File "main.py", line 67, in <module>
    corpus = data.Corpus(args.data)
File "C:\Users\archive\data.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.train = self.tokenize(os.path.join(path, 'train.txt'))
File "C:\Users\archive\data.py", line 28, in tokenize
    assert os.path.exists(path)
AssertionError
```

Comment: 1) Check that `args.data` contains what you think it does. 2) Does the file that variable refer to in fact exist on your filesystem?

Comment: Since you don't provide any command line arguments to `python main.py`, `args.data` will have its default value, `default='./data/wikitext-2'`.  It's your responsibility to make sure defaults like that are valid.